# SQL Server : Index creation on Large Tables

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

Is there any way to create the index quickly on large tables?

I have a partitioned table with 90 million records in 43 partitions. Normally it takes 10-14 hrs to create a non clustered index on it. Now I need to drop and recreate the index on some other column.

Any suggestions to reduce the time of index creation will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad. I'd suggest you do a quick internet search. That said, 14h for 90m rows is *a lot*. Investigate why it is that slow to be gin with. Just 1900 rows/sec. Should be 50x that for a reasonable schema.

Comment: Actually, as you are on Enterprise Edition you should be getting 50x the speed *per CPU core*.